# AlphaBlending width DirectX and SharpDX giving strange results

Tags: c#, wpf, directx, sharpdx

I've been trying to get AlphaBlending working with DX9 + SharpDX + WPF combination, but just can't get correct results out of it!

Here's how two triangles looks like, the first one being fully opague gray, and the other being same gray, but with alpha of 0.5.

[image]

The problem is that for some reason the half transparent gray is added to destination gray, even to my understanding it should be calculated with (Source * SourceFactor) + (Dest * DestFactor), which should be (0.5 * 0.5) + (0.5 * (1 - 0.5)) = 0.5, but it isn't.

The interesting parts of code:

```
device9.SetRenderState(D3D9.RenderState.AlphaBlendEnable, true);
device9.SetRenderState(D3D9.RenderState.SourceBlend, D3D9.Blend.SourceAlpha);
device9.SetRenderState(D3D9.RenderState.DestinationBlend, D3D9.Blend.InverseSourceAlpha);
device9.SetRenderState(D3D9.RenderState.BlendOperation, D3D9.BlendOperation.Add);
```

And I Have a HLSL shader, which takes position and color for vertexes, as well as one constant Alpha value, the pixel shader looks like this:

```
float4 PixelShaderFunction(VertexShaderOutput input) : COLOR0
{
    return float4(input.Color[0], input.Color[1], input.Color[2], input.Color[3] * Alpha);
}
```

Comment: So why is this wrong? It looks correct to me that if you have a half transparent object that you see the other objects through it and that's exactly what's happening here, right?

Comment: What are the values in input.Color and what is Alpha set to for both triangles?

Comment: @Jaska: Actually we need to see more code.  Something must be changing the DX9 blend state between you setting it as above and the DP/DIP call ...

Comment: @Goz WPF seems to require premultiplied alpha, so the solution was to set sourceblend to one and destination to invsourcealpha, and then premultiply in the shader code, still i don't fully understand this but works..